# Existing project not opening in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I am using netbeans 6.9.1 to work with a web project. My problem is when i am trying to open an existing web project, it is not showing the pop-up window to browse the location of existing project. I am facing the same kind of problem with the **add jar/folder** option also.. What is the problem here?? i unistalled and installed the netbeans but getting the same problem!!

Comment: Can you use a newer version of netbeans or are you constrained to use 6.9?

Comment: There is no constraint to use 6.9 only.. but i am using this version with other two systems also.But they are working well

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe upgrading to 7.0 might solve your problem. You could separately install 7.0 and try to open the project. If it still fails just uninstall it.

Comment: But it may not be a proper solution... In future i may get the same problem with version 7 also??

Comment: delete netbeans config folder.for example on Linux you must remove .netbeans folder located on home folder.

Comment: Perhaps you could look in the log to see if an Exception is being thrown. The log is located in `~/.netbeans/6.9/var/log/` and is called `messages.log`. If there's an Exception, post it here.